# Pandas Add value to Dataframe column based on index and if value exists then append

Tags: python, pandas

I'm assigning value to column based on index value and if value exists then append the new value to old value

I have tried applying value to column based on index but couldn't append value to already existing value in column

Dataframe:-

```
    foo   bar 
0   1     1          
1   2     2     
2   3     3     
3   3     3
```

Code :-

```
values = ['a', 'b']
for val in values:
   df.loc[df['foo'] == 1, foo2] = val
```

Outupt Dataframe:

```
    foo   bar   foo2  
0   1     1       b   
1   2     2     
2   3     3     
3   3     3
```

Expected DataFrame:-

```
    foo   bar   foo2  
0   1     1     a,b  
1   2     2     
2   3     3     
3   3     3
```

Comment: Please specify whether you want `foo2` to be a list of `a` and `b` (`[a, b]`), or a string of `a` and `b` separated by a comma (`a,b`)

Comment: @Tankred thank you for your reply I want a and b as a string

Answer (score 1):

As you noticed the line

```
df.loc[df['foo'] == 1, foo2] = b
```

overwrites previous value so that you end up with only `b`. Is there a particular reason you need to solve your problem this way? You can write a custom function and use apply to append values but this is not how pandas is supposed to be used.
I would recommend creating another column `'foo3'`. You can always join the letters afterwards.

Comment: Thank you for your reply i'm querying data base and there i'm getting two results with same id and there i want to append those two results to column with same index

Comment: First your database has a problem if ids are not unique. I would recommend to create a new row for each duplicate value. Repeat the values of `foo` and `bar` and have `a` and `b` in their respective rows. You can easily do that by reading your database (chunkwise or lazy with e.g. dask) and a left join.

Comment: Thank you for your reply problem got solved used your method.

Answer (score 0):

This should achieve what you are looking for. However, just as maow already pointed out, you should think about adding new columns and concatenating them when you need to.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'foo': [1,2,3,3], 'bar': [1,2,3,3], 'foo2':[None, None, None, None]})
print(df)

a = 'a'
b = 'b'

# insert a
df.loc[df['foo'] == 1, 'foo2'] = a
print(df)

# concat b to a
df.loc[df['foo'] == 1, 'foo2'] += ',' + b
print(df)
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply but i want to assigned the values in for loop

Answer (score 0):

This should solve your problem

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'foo': [1,2,3,3], 'bar': [1,2,3,3], 'foo2':[None, None, None, None]})
print(df)

print(df)
values = ['a', 'b']
for val in values:
    print(df.loc[df['foo'] == 1,'foo2'][0])
    if (df.loc[df['foo'] == 1,'foo2'][0]==None):
        df.loc[df['foo'] == 1, 'foo2']=val

    else:       
        df.loc[df['foo'] == 1, 'foo2']=df.loc[df['foo'] == 1:,'foo2'] + ',' +val

print(df)
```

output:

```
   foo  bar foo2
0    1    1  a,b
1    2    2
2    3    3
3    3    3
```

Comment: @thank you for your help but it didn't solved my problem

Comment: okk.. what is the problem you are facing then? i am confused now... :-|